# RegExp Literal from MySQL Database

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, regex

I want to get from database javascript literal regular expression and it's all fine exept that it is between quotation marks. What I can do to get this expression without quotations marks, please find example below.
Here is php file: http://klmgr.jest.guru/getjson.php that getting expressions from database
And below jQuery code:

```
    var sources = [];
    $.getJSON('http://klmgr.jest.guru/getjson.php?callback=?', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            sources.push(val.source);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert a string to a RegExp, use `new RegExp(string)`

```
var sources = [];
$.getJSON('http://klmgr.jest.guru/getjson.php?callback=?', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        sources.push(new RegExp(val.source));
    });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work well. I have the table like this:
[RegExp /\/^(.*(.|\/\/))?atemda.com\//, RegExp /\/^(.*(.|\/\/))?adv.adview\//, RegExp /\/^(.*(.|\/\/))?clk.onet\//, RegExp /\/^(.*(.|\/\/))?tags.qservz\//] 

I need this:
[/^(.*(.|//))?atemda.com/, /^(.*(.|//))?adv.adview/, /^(.*(.|//))?clk.onet/, /^(.*(.|//))?tags.qservz/, /^(.*(.|//))?serving-sys.com/, /^(.*(.|//))?smartadserver.com/, /^(.*(.|//))?tradedoubler.com/, /^(.*(.|//))?adocean.pl/]